# Remove shipping for specific products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I am looking to remove the shipping from few variable products in WooCommerce. I need that few products from cart directly go to PayPal.

I added the following code in my theme's functions.php file:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'disable_address_validation_for_specific_products' );
function disable_address_validation_for_specific_products( $fields ) {
    // Enter the product IDs of the variable products for which you want to disable address validation
    $product_ids = array(12, 34, 56);

    if (!empty(WC()->cart)) {
        foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
            $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

            if (in_array($product_id, $product_ids)) {
                unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['validate']);
                unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']['validate']);
                unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['validate']);
                unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']['validate']);
                unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']['validate']);
                break; // Stop the loop after finding the first matching product
            }
        }
    }

    return $fields;
}
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_false' );
```

Now, for all products, shipping is disabled, what I don't want.

Also, I get those errors on the checkout page:

- **Error# 1** No shipping method has been selected. Please double-check your address, or contact us if you need any help.
- **Error # 2** Please enter an address to continue.

What I am doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean `shipping` as `shipping address` or `shipping rates`?

Comment: "I need that few products from cart directly go to paypal" - Woocommerce offers affiliate product type no need to do complicating stuff.

Comment: No shipping method has been selected. Please double check your address, or contact us if you need any help. I need to remove Shipping.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes a and missing things to get that working… Try the following instead:

```php
// Custom conditional function that check for specific cart items
function has_unshippable_cart_items(){
    // Add the product IDs that will disable address validation
    $product_ids = array(12, 34, 56);

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item) {
        if ( count( array_intersect([$item['product_id'], $item['variation_id']], $product_ids) ) > 0 ) {
            return true;
        }
    } 
    return false; 
}

// Acting on checkout billing fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'disable_address_validation_for_specific_products' );
function disable_address_validation_for_specific_products( $billing_fields ) {
    // Only on checkout page
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        // The related targeted billing fields
        $field_keys = ['address_1', 'city', 'postcode', 'country', 'state'];

        if (has_unshippable_cart_items()) {
            // Loop through the field keys array
            foreach ($field_keys as $field_key) {
                $billing_fields["billing_{$field_key}"]['required'] = false;
                unset($billing_fields["billing_{$field_key}"]['validate']);
            }
        }
    }
    return $billing_fields;
}
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', 'filter_cart_needs_shipping_address' );
function filter_cart_needs_shipping_address( $needs_shipping ) {
    return has_unshippable_cart_items() ? false : $needs_shipping;
}
```

Tested and works.

Code goes in the functions.php file of your child theme, or in a plugin file.